# Ejecutar 2 funciones a la vez, con distintos time sleep

Tags: python-3.x

soy nuevo en esto y necesito hacer correr 2 funciones a la vez, pero ambas con tiempos de sleep distintos.
Necesito que la primera se ejecute cada 5 segundos y la segunda cuando la condición se cumpla esperar 300 seg.
El código ejecuta la primera función pero la segunda no me la ejecuta.
Alguna ayuda porfa...

El código es el siguiente:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def function1():
        i_data()
        time.sleep(5)
        
async def function2():
        stage = i_data()
        print(stage)
        if stage == 4:
            get_json()
            time.sleep(300)


async def main():
    while True:
        f1 = loop.create_task(function1())
        f2 = loop.create_task(function2())
        await asyncio.wait([f1, f2])
    

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Comment: ¿Donde esta definida `get_json()`?

Comment: Buenas, he probado el codigo y funciona. El problema fijate que en el segundo loop estas expresando el tiempo en medida diferente. Usa time,sleep(3) y funcionara.